# Cucumber BDD Custom Parameter Definition not working for feature with examples

Tags: java, cucumber, serenity-bdd

I'm trying to write step definitions with Serenity Cucumber BDD

### This is my feature:

```
@test1
      Scenario Outline: I need to try to Sign up as a new user 
            Given I have clicked on the Sign up link
            When I enter <username> and <password>
            And I click on sign up button
            Then I must see Success message
            Examples:
                  | username   | password |
                  | user001    | test123  |
                  | user002    | test123  |
```

---

My step definition

---

```
 @When(value = "I enter {word} and {word}")
    public void iAddUserNameAndPassword(String userName, String password) {
        user.addNewUserInfo(userName, password);
```

---

How can I use "userName" and "password" instead of "word" in the step definition

### I try to give the parameter definition shown below, but it doesn't work

```
@ParameterType("word")  // regexp
    public String userName(String userName){  // type, name (from method)
        return new String(userName);       // transformer function
    }
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Cucumber you've got it almost right. I don't actually know what Serenity does.

The parameter type annotation should have a value that is a regular expression. This regular expression should match the values used in your step.

```
@ParameterType("[a-z0-9]+")
public String userName(String value){
    return value;
}

@ParameterType("[a-z0-9]+")
public String password(String value){
    return value;
}
```

Then in your step definition you can use the method names of the annotated methods as parameter types.

```
@When("I enter {userName} and {password}")
public void iAddUserNameAndPassword(String userName, String password) {
    user.addNewUserInfo(userName, password);
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: weird, didnt work for me! for the username parameter I guess you have a typo with the "new" in front of the value but non the less I get following error:



`Suppressed: io.cucumber.java.InvalidMethodSignatureException: A @ParameterType annotated method must have one of these signatures:
 * public Author parameterName(String all)
 * public Author parameterName(String captureGroup1, String captureGroup2, ...ect )
 * public Author parameterName(String... captureGroups)`

Comment: my bad i had the  @ParameterType("username") and @ParameterType("password") above the step definition but thats not neccessary and thus throwing the fault.

your solution works perfect